# Convert std::string to STRSAFE_LPCWSTR in an utility method

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm trying out Windows Notification using Win32 API.
This is the method I have:

```
BOOL Notification::ShowNotification(std::string title, std::string info) {
  NOTIFYICONDATA nid = {
    sizeof(nid)
  };
  nid.uFlags = NIF_INFO | NIF_GUID;
  nid.guidItem = __uuidof(AppIcon);
  nid.dwInfoFlags = NIIF_USER | NIIF_LARGE_ICON;

  std::wstring wtitle = std::wstring(title.begin(), title.end());
  const wchar_t * wchar_title = (STRSAFE_LPCWSTR) wtitle.c_str();
  StringCchCopy(nid.szInfoTitle, sizeof(nid.szInfoTitle), wchar_title);

  std::wstring wInfo = std::wstring(info.begin(), info.end());
  const wchar_t * wchar_Info = (STRSAFE_LPCWSTR) wInfo.c_str();
  StringCchCopy(nid.szInfo, sizeof(nid.szInfo), wchar_Info);

  LoadIconMetric(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_NOTIFICATIONICON), LIM_LARGE, & nid.hBalloonIcon);
  return Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, & nid);
}
```

As you can see, there is duplicate code for converting the `string` type to `STRSAFE_LPCWSTR` for the variables `title` and `info`. I was thinking of a small utility method that would replace the duplicate code.
Something like this:

```
void Notification::ConvertToLPCWSTR(std::string input, STRSAFE_LPCWSTR &result)
{
  std::wstring wide_string = std::wstring(input.begin(), input.end());
  result = (STRSAFE_LPCWSTR)wide_string.c_str();
}
```

And then use it from the `ShowNotification` method like this, where `wchar_title` is passed by reference:

```
STRSAFE_LPCWSTR wchar_title;
ConvertToLPCWSTR(title, wchar_title);
```

But it is failing because `wide_string` variable is stack allocated and it goes out of scope when `ConvertToLPCWSTR` execution is finished, because of which `wchar_title` is pointing at deallocated memory.

Anyone know of a good way to fix this ?

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: You don't need any conversions. Just fix your interfaces to take UTF-16 encoded strings proper (aka `std::wstring` with any given Windows compiler).

Comment: `std::wstring(info.begin(), info.end())` is not the correct way to convert a `std::string` to a `std::wstring`. That will only work for ASCII strings. Otherwise, you need to *convert* the data, using `MultiByteToWideChar()`, `std::wstring_convert`, or equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move all three lines of the repeated code into a small utility function.

```
static void Notification::ConvertToLPCWSTR(const std::string& input, LPWSTR result, size_t result_max_size) {
  std::wstring wInfo = std::wstring(input.begin(), input.end());
  const wchar_t * wchar_Info = (STRSAFE_LPCWSTR) wInfo.c_str();
  StringCchCopy(result, result_max_size, wchar_Info);
}
```

And call like

```
ConvertToLPCWSTR(info, nid.szInfo, sizeof(nid.szInfo));
```

Comment: Thanks S.M. So the idea is populate the target, before the stack variable goes out of scope, by passing the target itself into the method. I'm used to mostly working in C#, where I could have just returned the converted value from the utility method, which will be then used by the callee.

Comment: `std::wstring wInfo = std::wstring(input.begin(), input.end())` doesn't do anything meaningful for any character encoding. With the exception of ASCII. And yes, that expression is so wrong, that it mandates a down-vote.

Comment: This is converting the data types (`char` to `wchar_t`), it is not converting the encoding.